# Does RASA Integration with MS Teams support Adaptive Cards?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

### Problem Statement

> 1. We need to integrate our chat developed in RASA to work on MS Teams Channel.
> 2. The Chat bot needs to show  Images, Carousals , Buttons, Text Boxes, Dropdown boxes to show data and accept inputs from the user on MS Teams  Channel

### Query:

**Does RASA** Integration with **MS Teams** support **Adaptive Cards**(Images, Carousals , Buttons, Text Boxes, Dropdown boxes) like MS Botframework Supports or is it mostly a Text and simple Button based interface?

Answer (score 0):

The botframework channel doesn't employ any python wrappers, it interacts with the [post message uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#activity-object) directly [code reference](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/main/rasa/core/channels/botframework.py#L94-L101).

That endpoint expects an Activity object, which itself can contain Attachments like adaptive cards etc. So any sort of Activity you could render from that endpoint, you can send from Rasa via the [`send_custom_json()`](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/main/rasa/core/channels/botframework.py#L152-L162) method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does!. You can use utter_message(json_message=) with some specifications!