# change front-end of a MS Teams Bot application

Tags: botframework, rasa, fluent-ui

I used rasa to build a bot and connected it to the MS botframework. This gave me a decent embedded bot in MS Teams. However, I want to rewrite part of the default front-end provided by botframework. For example, I want to change the style of buttons, design my own cards, etc. Fluent-UI can be used to design Teams-style elements, but I don't know how to integrate these changes with botframework. Is this feasible? Thank you so much!

Edit: For instance, the default text and Rasa buttons are shown in Teams as the following:
[image]

But I want to achieve a nicer interface, like self-designed cards, different button styles, etc:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the default front-end provided by botframework"? The front end is Teams in your case. Are you imagining that Teams is part of the Bot Framework?

Comment: No. I mean with botframework I can connect my bot to teams without having to write frontend code, but now I want to customize some frontend elements (e.g., change the size and style of the buttons written in Rasa response). Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying you want to create your own Teams client? Or are you wondering if you can get the Teams app that everyone is already using to display arbitrary HTML that your bot sends to it? Can you edit your question to include screenshots of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I upload the screenshots. Basically I want to make the bot responses more beautiful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to styling options, that's controlled by Teams and is largely outside your control. However, when it comes to layout, you have a great deal of control because Teams supports Adaptive Cards. Read more about Adaptive Cards here:

- https://adaptivecards.io/
- https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Regarding the RASA part of your question, have a look at this: [Does RASA Integration with MS Teams support Adaptive Cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104554/does-rasa-integration-with-ms-teams-support-adaptive-cards)